# Adding border to image in cell's imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like to add a border to a TVC cell's image through the imageView and the imageView layer

I've got code that works for the cell.layer itself, but as soon as I change it to the cell.imageView.layer, the code does nothing at all.

I'm using it within tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath and am in Xcode 4.6.3, iOS 6.x

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

CALayer* layer;
//layer = cell.layer;
layer = cell.imageView.layer;
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
[layer setBorderWidth:10.0f];
```

This works if applied to cell.layer, but does nothing at all to the cell's imageView.layer.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** FYI, I am importing `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

**EDIT:** though this works against the cell just fine, that is because the cell already has a border color defined as black.  The imageView does not and therefore requires a border color to be set like so:

```
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];  
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];  
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:.5f green:.6f blue:.3f alpha:.75f] CGColor ]];
```

Comment: Try it in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Tried it.  I have the answer now.  TY.

Comment: Have you logged cell.imageView.layer to see if it's non-nil?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is, add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

FrameWork and use

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
cell.imageView.layer.setMasksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks but you misunderstand what I'm doing.  I have to have imported Quartzcore or this would throw errors.  I am already setting the borderWidth with layer setBorderWidth.

Comment: @AlexZavatone You imported Quartz, but did you actually link against it in your build phases?

Comment: 0x7ffffff, yes, if I didn't, the code would not work when testing it against the cell's layer, and that works just fine.

Comment: what do you want to do ? i cannot understand :(

Comment: iPatel, I am trying to add a border to the image within a cell.  Though your suggestion should work, it is what I am already doing, and it has no effect to the cell's image.

Comment: It appears that the background color for a cell is already set, but this needs to be set for the cell's imageView as the color is not set.

Comment: cell.imageView.backGroundColor = cell.backGroundColor;

Answer (score 1):

Though this code works against the cell just fine, that is because the cell already has a border color defined as black.  The imageView does not and therefore requires a border color to be set like so:

```
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];  
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];  
[cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:.5f green:.6f blue:.3f alpha:.75f] CGColor ]];
```